# How to create SSIS package for deleting records by joining two tables of different servers without using linked servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am tyring to create a SSIS packet that delete records from a table in one server(Production server) by joining it with the other table in different server (development server). The example of the query is as below. We cannot create new table in server001, the production server but we can in server002, the development server.

```
Delete tb1
from server0001.Database1.dbo.table1 tb1
inner join server0002.Database2.dbo.table2 tb2 on tb1.ColumnId = tb2.ColumnId
```

Comment: how to create SSIS package for the above query.@xedni

Comment: @SM, From this question and some of your other recent SSIS questions, it seems that you might be brand new to SSIS. It's probably worth watching some youtube videos or going through some tutorials to get stronger foundation to start from. Good luck!